# SQL - how to build cohort analysis

Tags: sql, postgresql

Ok so right now I'm pulling data from SQL and it looks like this:

```
Cohort     Date     Revenue
---------------------------
Dec 16    Dec 16    30.00  
Dec 16    Jan 17    31.00  
Dec 16    Feb 17    32.00  
Jan 17    Jan 17    40.00  
Jan 17    Feb 17    41.00  
Feb 18    Feb 17    50.00
```

What I want is this:

```
Cohort  |           Date           
        | Month0 | Month1 | Month2 
--------|--------|--------|--------
Dec 16  | 30.00  | 31.00  | 32.00  
Jan 17  | 40.00  | 41.00  |
Feb 18  | 50.00  |        |
```

Right now I go into excel and do SUMPRODUCT to convert it - which takes resources and time.

Is there a way to get second view out of SQL straight away? Assume I'm SQL 101 please - I've been doing it for a month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window function `dense_rank` and then use aggregation to pivot the table.

```
select cohort,
    sum(case when rn = 1 then Revenue end) Month0,
    sum(case when rn = 2 then Revenue end) Month1,
    sum(case when rn = 3 then Revenue end) Month2
from (
    select t.*,
        dense_rank() over (
            partition by cohort order by to_date('01-' || date, 'dd-Mon-yy')
            ) rn
    from your_table t
    ) t
group by cohort
```

Comment: I found this difficult to interpret but it did work when I used or a similar exercise!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also use crosstab function to create a pivot table.
Before using these example you need to install the extension

> CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc

After that you can execute this query. To achieve dec 16 comes first i have sorted beginning with year-month-day:

```
select *
from crosstab(
$$select t.cohort,
         t.date,
         sum(t.revenue)
  from your_table t
  group by t.cohort,t.date
  order by to_char(to_date('01-'||t.cohort,'dd-Mon-yy'),'YYYYMMDD'),
           to_char(to_date('01-'||t.date,'dd-Mon-yy'),'YYYYMMDD') asc
$$) 
as months(cohort text,Month0 NUMERIC,Month1 NUMERIC,Month2 NUMERIC)
```